# Getting deeper meaning getting stronger

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine there is a couple who's love is getting more solid and strong as time passes. They have lived e.g 20 years and in spite of other's expectation they fall in love more and more. I was wondering if someone could let me know if in English the way I am trying to say the sentence below sounds natural:

> - Their love **will get deeper** (meaning gets stronger) as time passes.

Comment: Sure. You can fall more *deeply* in love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example using

> will get deeper

only talks about the future of their love without accounting for the past, which your question frames as a deepening process also.

A couple of ways to say this

> They *became more deeply in love* as time passed.
>   Their love *grew* deeper as time passed.

often love is described as *growing* over time (as opposed to *getting*), both these sentences refer to past and future sates of their love.

"Deeper" also has the meaning of "stronger" in learning.

> deeper understanding = stronger understanding *(and includes more detailed understanding)*